# xcode error: there is no sdk for "iphoneos2.2.1"

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

So I downloaded a sample application and I'm guessing it was made before the iphone os 4. And when I try to compile it gives me that error.

I don't know if the programming would be any different. Can someone tell me if there were any changes in programming between os 2.2.1 and os 4? How do I make this application compatible for os 4?

Thanks,
Elijah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there have been changes. You should read the docs on developer.apple.com to get up to speed.

If you are on the latest version of the SDK but have a project that is targeting an older version that you don't have you can change the target by highlighting the project file in xcode and clicking the info button, then change the 'Base SDK' setting in the build options.

It will then probably build and run without errors, but there may well be warnings if the example is using old and deprecated features and even if there arent, there may be new easier or better ways of doing the same thing so I'd takes some time to read over the changes at developer.apple.com and get up to speed

Comment: Thanks now I get this error: "Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: Bill Dudney' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain" I'm guessing that's the person who made this application. Any ideas?

Comment: In the same place (click on info on the project file, then look at the build options) there is a setting called 'Code Signing Identity'. In there change the identity to you.

Comment: There are soooo many errors for things like: prior to os3 type of thing....bahhh.....ANy suggestions?

Comment: Depends what the example you have is trying to do, it might be best to look for a more up to date example or ask specific question on here about how to do the stuff the example does.

Comment: actually this is where I found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240617/cfnetwork-and-bonjour-integration-for-iphone-to-mac-integration
I don't know if there are any newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

The application that you have downloaded is made in the os 2.2.1 and in your application there won't be os 2.2.1, there might be 3.0 or higher version of os is available.

To run this application simply change the base sdk to 3.0 or as per the sdk available in your mac.

use following steps

1. click in target, application name.
2. press info button.
3. change the base sdk to 3.0 or higher as available with your mac and your application will run.

Comment: Great! look at the other answer's comment...that's what's happening now.