# Connect iOS app to Mac app over wifi? Similar to iTunes Remote?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, connection

I'm wondering if it's possible for me to connect an iOS app with a Mac app over wifi, in a similar way to remote and iTunes, where it pairs the devices up so they can communicate with each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. Use [Bonjour](http://www.apple.com/support/bonjour/) for search and discovery. It's easy and will work through the wifi.

**EDIT**

Look at this answer for code samples https://stackoverflow.com/a/3242187/277021