# How do i create a connection between my iPhone app with my mac app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos, wifi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ad Hoc Wifi Connection Between iPhone & Mac - Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848525/ad-hoc-wifi-connection-between-iphone-mac-possible)
>   [How can I create a small Mac app that receives data over the WiFi network from an iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902282/how-can-i-create-a-small-mac-app-that-receives-data-over-the-wifi-network-from-a)
>   [Connect iOS app to Mac app over wifi? Similar to iTunes Remote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555241/connect-ios-app-to-mac-app-over-wifi-similar-to-itunes-remote)

I want to create a connection between my iPhone app and my mac app over wifi. What ways are there of doing this? Are there any open source projects which work on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Bonjour. There appears to be some decent information here - http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/ - but also the Apple docs are probably a good place to start.

You could also roll your own connection mechanism but discovering will be quite an effort which is something that Bonjour solves for you.