# Stream iPhone camera to iMac

Tags: ios, macos, network-programming

I'm interested in streaming the camera feed of my iPhone to my iMac. I've already figured out how to extract the camera frames; this works just fine. The problem I'm having is figuring out how to stream these frames over my local network to the iMac. I've searched around SO, but most of the good answers (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240617/cfnetwork-and-bonjour-integration-for-iphone-to-mac-integration/3242187#3242187), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902282/how-can-i-create-a-small-mac-app-that-receives-data-over-the-wifi-network-from-a?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610790/how-do-i-create-a-connection-between-my-iphone-app-with-my-mac-app?noredirect=1&lq=1)) are really old, so the links are dead or the libraries are outdated.

I'm also very inexperienced when it comes to writing networking code, so I'm also a little unclear as to where to start. What's the standard method for communicating between an iOS device and a MacOS device?