# Use iPhone as a game controller in a tvOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multipeer-connectivity, apple-tv, tvos

During the Apple TV announcement, the developers of Crossy Road demonstrated using an iPhone as a 2nd controller for an Apple tv game:

http://www.macrumors.com/2015/09/09/cooperative-play-for-crossy-road/

My first thought was to implement this using the [Multipeer Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html). However, it's not supported on tvOS. Is there a good way to connect an iPhone to an Apple TV without Multipeer Connectivity?

**Update:** It doesn't appear that I can use GameKit because GKPeerPickerController has been removed from GameKit on tvOS.

Answer (score 10):

You can try my library. I built this for my apps maybe helpful for you too.

https://github.com/vivianaranha/TvOS_Remote

Apple TV Project (Receiver)

Step 1: Create a TvOS Project and import the files from RemoteReceiver

libRemoteReceiver.a

RemoteReceiver.h

Step 2: In your ViewController.m file import the RemoteReceiver.h file

```
#import "RemoteReceiver.h"
```

Step 3: Inside ViewController.m file add the following code

```
@interface ViewController () <RemoteReceiverDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) RemoteReceiver *remoteReceiver;
@end
```

Step 4: Inside viewDidLoad alloc and set the delegate for remoteReceiver

```
self.remoteReceiver = [[RemoteReceiver alloc] init];
self.remoteReceiver.delegate = self;
```

Step 5: Implement the following delegate method for messages send from iOS remote app

```
-(void) didReceiveMessage:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
}
```

iOS Project (Sender/Remote Control)

Step 1: Create an iOS Project and import the files from RemoteSender

libRemoteSender.a

RemoteSender.h

Step 2: Import the RemoteSender class in your ViewController

```
#import "RemoteSender.h"
```

Step 3: Update ViewController.m with the following code

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) RemoteSender *remoteSender;
@end
```

Step 4: Allocate and initialize the remoteSender object

```
self.remoteSender = [[RemoteSender alloc] init];
```

Step 5: Implement gestures and methods (Check below for just button code)

```
- (IBAction)sendSomeInformation:(id)sender {
    NSDictionary *theDictionaryToSendToTV = @{@"name": @"John Smith",@"age": @"35", @"address":@"123 Main St"};
    [self.remoteSender sendInfo:theDictionaryToSendToTV];
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting. Is there any chance you could add support to send and receive custom events? Like say a userInfo NSDictionary perhaps.

Comment: I can customize to add anything right now. I will make it more useful in a few days. Currently I am working on a multiplayer app of my own

Comment: This looks great. How can you be sure that you're connecting to the correct Apple TV? I don't see an IDs

Comment: Hi! Why is there no arm64 support?

Comment: I'm not able to build any of your example projects, it keeps telling me `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RemoteReceiver", referenced from:
`

Comment: I have added the entire source code to github - Please do take a look - I dont want to restrict people from using this - being very busy at work these days

Comment: The iPhone never connects to the tv for me, and thus crashes on sendInfo to the sender object. I reported an issue at Github.

Answer (score 7):

I've developed a framework that supports the creation of software-based controllers and directs the input through a MFi profile, allowing you to have a single codebase that handles both software and hardware controllers.  Many other features as well:

https://github.com/robreuss/VirtualGameController

NSNetservice is used for connectivity, and all Apple platforms are supported (iOS, OS X, watchOS and tvOS).

All features:

- Mimics API for Apple's *GameController* framework (GCController)
- Device motion support in software controllers
- Custom controller elements
- Custom element mapping
- WiFi-based, with Bluetooth fallback
- Controller-forwarding
- Works with Apple TV Simulator
- Unlimited number of hardware controllers on Apple TV (using controller forwarding)
- Ability to enhance inexpensive slide-on/form-fitting controllers with motion, extended profile elements and custom elements
- iCade controller support (mapped through the MFi profiles so they appear as MFi hardware)
- Easy-to-implement 3d touch on software controllers
- Leverage on-screen and Bluetooth keyboards using software controllers (including with Apple TV)
- Support for snapshots (compatible with Apple's snapshot format)
- Swift 2.1
- Framework-based

Comment: This should be the accept answer in an ideal world!

Comment: Thanks!  I hope some folks find it useful.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `CFNetwork` is available on TvOS.  Try [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240617/cfnetwork-and-bonjour-integration-for-iphone-to-mac-integration) for help on using `CFNetwork`.

EDIT: also take a look at `CoreBluetooth`.  I'm working on the same issue - I want to have a companion iPhone app for my TvOS app.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure it qualifies as a "good way", but `GKMatchRequest` and `GKMatchmaker` are in there, so maybe that's what they're using.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchRequest_Ref/

Comment: Unfortunately, GKPeerPickerController has been removed from GameKit on tvOS.

Comment: Not sure if this is supported on tvOS https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html