# How to use iPhone as Game Controller for OS X, iOS or tvOS

Tags: ios, macos, tvos, gamecontroller

I am looking for some sample code that would allow an app on iOS to function as a game controller for an app running on OS X (and in future tvOS or another iOS device such as the iPadPro).  The controller needs to support the following:
- connecting to the game
- selecting and controlling a vehicle via custom buttons in the controller app
- displaying status information of the selected vehicle, such as fuel, speed, etc.

Any pointers to sample code and/or recommended API's that should be used would be welcome.

EDIT:

I found this sample app from Apple which will probably do the job.  Any better options out there?
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html

I have posted a DTS request so will update this when I get an answer

EDIT:
FYI: Apps approved by Apple but be sure to include a note to the reviewer explaining the need for network server services in the entitlements.

Comment: For those who mark this question down please be kind enough to explain why you are doing so.

Comment: Because "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." as someone with 3.3k rep you would be expected to know this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513901/use-iphone-as-a-game-controller-in-a-tvos-app

Comment: Thanks @DanielStorm but that doesn't really provide an answer to my question does it? Kind of looks like a similar question though.

Comment: You might consider asking Apple's Developer Technical Support (DTS) group this question… see: <https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#requestTechSupport>

Comment: @geowar good idea, I might just do that before I waste time going down the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered in developer forums by an Apple Staff.

> Hi Aaron - You could look at options such as Bonjour discovery on the
>   local network, or perhaps use CoreBluetooth to make use of Bluetooth
>   LE.

[Link to post.](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/52191#52191)